# Listview pagination and GET parameters on the next page

Tags: yii2

I have this `UrlManager` rule:

```
'<pageSlug>-pa<pageId:\d+>' => 'page/page',
```

Then I have page with url like this `domain.com/blog-pa54`

In this example I have

`pageSlug = blog` and `pageId = 54`

In my view I have `ListView` with my blog posts.

I set my dataprovider like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => BlogPost::find()
                ->where([
                    'active' => 1
                ]),
            'pagination' => [
                'defaultPageSize' => 3,
                //'params' => [], when I set this, it only shows get param "page"
                'pageParam' => 'page',
                'route' => $pageURL, // this variable is equal to "blog-pa54"
            ],
        ]);
```

My route is current url slug - `blog-pa54`
When I go to next page I recieve this url: `blog-pa54?pageSlug=blog&pageId=54&page=2`

How can I remove $_GET params `pageSlug` and `pageId` from url?
I try to set `pagination > params = []` and it remove this get param, but when I go to other page it doesn't change items in my ListView

Here is also my `ListView` and `LinkPager`

```
<div class="blog-post-wrapper">
    <?= ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $blogPostsDataprovider,
        'itemOptions' => ['tag' => null],
        'options' => [
            'tag' => false,
        ],
        'layout' => "{summary}<div class='row'>{items}</div>",
        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($page) {
            return $this->render('//blog-post/_blogPostList', [
                'page' => $page,
                'model' => $model
            ]);
        },
    ]); ?>
</div>

<?= \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $blogPostsDataprovider->pagination,
    'linkContainerOptions' => [
        'class' => 'page-item',
    ],
    'linkOptions' => [
        'class' => 'page-link',
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Simply setting route as `'route' => '<controller-id>/<action-id>'` instead of final url should do the trick because pagination uses url manager to generate urls. So in your case it should be `'route' => 'page/page'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.
`params` attribute must not be empty.

You can set it like this:

```
'params' => [
    'page' => isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1,
]
```

Or if you have another get params like get filters:

```
$getParams = [];
        if(isset($_GET)){
            foreach($_GET as $getKey => $getValue){
                if(in_array($getKey, ['pageSlug', 'pageId'])){ //here I skip my params from UrlManager rule
                    continue;
                }
                $getParams[$getKey] = $getValue;
            }
        }
.....
'params' => $getParams
```